# How can I solve 'Access Denied' with ASP and Windows 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to save a file like this:

```
 FileStream file = 
     new FileStream(“C:\\temp”, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
 Byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
 File.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
 File.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 File.Close();
 File.Close();
```

I then get this error:

> Access to the path ‘C:\temp’ is denied.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path ‘C:\temp’ is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.   To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the
>   file in File Explorer, choose “Properties” and select the Security
>   tab. Click “Add” to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the
>   ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

I’ve done this on both my Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines and got the same error message.  I’ve changed the administrator role on the pc, given full control to all users, removed the ‘Read Only’ attribute from the file and still got the same error.  I even tried using a thumb drive.

I also noticed that after removing the ‘Read-Only’ attribute from the file, it always returns as if the setting did not take.

I also tried this fix with the Windows 7 machine:  http://fixmywin.com/fix-windows-7-access-denied-error-and-permission-ownership-problem/...but still the same errors. I gave up after about fie hours with this problem.  How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Look in IIS at the ApplicationPool the site is running under, select "Advanced Settings" and find the user the App Pool is using.  This will typically be "NETWORK SERVICE" unless you have specifically changed it.  Then, right click on the folder c:\temp >> Properties >> Security and add "NETWORK SERVICE" (or other user) with "Modify", "Full Control" or the appropriate permissions for your app.